# How to make more anagrams from one word

Tags: python

I am able to make one anagram via this code

```
import random
x = input()
x = list(x)
random.shuffle(x)
y = "".join(x)
print(y)
```

but I dont know how to specife how many times it should generate anagram.

Comment: Maybe you would be happier with permutations: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop so that once you have entered your word and recieved the anagram, the program asks whether you want another anagram. This process continues after you tell it to stop by typing 'n' when it asks if you would like to repeat the process.

**Here is the code:**

```
import random

while True:
    question = input('\nYour Word: ')

    question = list(question)
    random.shuffle(question)
    y = "".join(question)

    print('Your Output is: ',y)

    question2 = input('\nWould you like to repeat this process with a different word? ')

    if question2 == 'n':
        print('Ok. Thanks for using this anagram maker :D')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Is here any option, how to make for example 5 anagrams without asking again for input?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations

for anagram in permutations("abcd"):
    print("".join(anagram))
```

It generates all anagrams for a given word. To specify how many times you would like it to generate a new anagram, do this:

```
from itertools import permutations

n_anagrams = 3
all_anagrams = ["".join(anagram) for anagram in permutations("abcd")]
print(all_anagrams[:n_anagrams])
```

Hope you can find this piece of code useful.

Comment: First one works well, but second doesnt. What exactly means the ":" in last line?

Comment: The `array[:N]` means "look at the array and take only the first N items from it". if `array` is `[a,b,c,d]`, and `N` is 2, the `array[:N]` is then `[a,b]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say create a function which takes in 2 inputs(`x`, the letters and `num`, the number of anagrams you want to generate). Within that function I would do this:

```
import random

def generateAnagrams(x, num):

   anagrams = []
   for i in range(num):
      random.shuffle(x)
      y = "".join(x)
      anagrams.append(y)
   print(anagrams)
```

If you want to call the function, just do this:

```
x = input()
x = list(x)

#Set num to an int that is the number of anagrams you want
num = 3
generateAnagrams(x, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to take into consideration the possibility that the input word has duplicate letters, so just using `permuatations` is not enough -- you need to remove the duplicate permutations *and* the original word, which is included among the permutations:

```
import itertools

def anagram(word):
    s = set(itertools.permutations(word)) - set([tuple(word)])
    return [''.join(permutation) for permutation in s]

print(anagram('ass'))
print(anagram('ready'))
```

Prints:

```
['sas', 'ssa']
['yarde', 'yaedr', 'yadre', 'yader', 'edayr', 'edyar', 'yeard', 'erady', 'erday', 'eardy', 'eadry', 'dyrae', 'dyare', 'ardye', 'aryde', 'yerda', 'yedra', 'earyd', 'eayrd', 'edray', 'edary', 'aydre', 'rdeay', 'eyrda', 'eydra', 'rdaey', 'adeyr', 'adyer', 'aredy', 'ardey', 'yared', 'yaerd', 'daeyr', 'dayer', 'dyrea', 'edrya', 'edyra', 'dyera', 'rdyea', 'eyadr', 'eydar', 'rdeya', 'rydae', 'eadyr', 'eaydr', 'draye', 'dryae', 'rdaye', 'rdyae', 'ayder', 'redya', 'reyda', 'reday', 'ayedr', 'aeryd', 'aeyrd', 'raeyd', 'rayed', 'erdya', 'eryda', 'ydear', 'ydaer', 'adrey', 'adery', 'dreya', 'dryea', 'derya', 'deyra', 'darey', 'daery', 'yrade', 'yrdae', 'radey', 'raedy', 'erayd', 'eryad', 'dyear', 'dyaer', 'dreay', 'draey', 'adrye', 'adyre', 'aerdy', 'deray', 'deary', 'yerad', 'areyd', 'aryed', 'aedyr', 'aeydr', 'ayrde', 'ayred', 'ayerd', 'radye', 'rayde', 'yeadr', 'yedar', 'yreda', 'yrdea', 'ryeda', 'rydea', 'eyrad', 'eyard', 'darye', 'dayre', 'ydrea', 'ydera', 'ryead', 'ryaed', 'yread', 'yraed', 'deyar', 'deayr', 'ydrae', 'ydare', 'reyad', 'ryade', 'aedry', 'reayd']
```

This generates *all* the anagrams of the original word. You can select one or all of these.